# access the values form the following JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How do I access the second number "19", which is in the Numbers array in the following JSON? I've tried every which way and have not been able to.

```
{
  "Numbers": [{
    "1": 6
  }, {
    "2": 19
  }, {
    "3": 34
  }, {
    "4": 38
  }, {
    "5": 70
  }],
  "MB": 5,
  "MP": "05",
  "DrawDate": "2016-03-22T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: `myVar.Numbers[1]['2']`

Comment: in which language ??

Comment: Javascript is the language

Comment: I just noticed myVar.Numbers[1]['2']  works but how?  I would think the following would work myVar.Numbers[1].2?

Comment: [Any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier can only be accessed using the square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Comment: @ConfusedDeer You reference to a numbered key in that way, just like you can't do `var 2 = 3;`

Comment: @AlonEitan, so if my JSON key was "two", instead of "2" then would myVar.Numbers[1].two be valid?

Comment: @AlonEitan never mind Rayon answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would access it like this:

```
console.log(jsonObj.Numbers[1][2]);
```

This assumes that you store that JSON into a variable called `jsonObj`.
You cannot use numbers as object property key's so you cant just do `jsonObj.Numbers[1].2`.

Answer (score 4):

You can access with:

```
object.Numbers[1]['2']
```

That is because the `Numbers` object is an array of key-value objects in which is your desired value.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it with

```
obj.Numbers[1][2]
```

where `1` is the object's index in the array and `2` its `key`

Answer (score 1):

To do this you should parse it into Javascript, like so:

```
var myjson = JSON.parse('{"Numbers":[{"1":6},{"2":19},{"3":34},{"4":38},{"5":70}],"MB":5,"MP":"05","DrawDate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00"}');
```

Once it's been parsed you can do

```
myjson.Numbers[1][2]
```

To access the key (**2**: 19) as well you would do

```
myjson.Numbers[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the whole json to var.

```
var obj = JSON.parse({"Numbers":[{"1":6},{"2":19},{"3":34},{"4":38},{"5":70}],"MB":5,"MP":"05","DrawDate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00"});



obj.Numbers[1][2]
```

You should be able to access it

Comment: You don't need to use JSON.parse because it's already JSON and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very easy :

```
var myVars={"Numbers":[{"1":6},{"2":19},{"3":34},{"4":38},{"5":70}],"MB":5,"MP":"05","DrawDate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00"}
```

`myVars.Numbers` will give you : `[{"1":6},{"2":19},{"3":34},{"4":38},{"5":70}]`
This element is an array:  the first element `myVars.Numbers[0]` is `{"1":6}`, the second `myVars.Numbers[1]` is `{"2":19}`. 
Finaly , `myVars.Numbers[1][2]` is 19. That means if you want to acces to your second number `19` you have to write : `myVars.Numbers[1][2]`

Comment: I think it is easy, but as Rayon Dabre mentioned, the one thing to keep in mind is that the JSON format does not support a invalid character, "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined...